# Points in Two surface Mapping Problem

Tags: computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, map-projections

First, this is 3d problem.

I have two circle type line (closed), these line shape don't need to be Perfect Circle. They don't need to be in one plane.

Based on the lines, we can get a surface and the domain which line will be the boundary.

Let say line A will give domain A, line B will give domain B.

Now there are many points, they are in domain A. I want to **find the corresponding points in domain B.**

The corresponding points means:

> The domain A deformed (it may involves enlarging, shrinking,
>   translation, rotation and reflection) to domain B. The points will
>   also move with the deformation, and the final position in domain B
>   is what I want.

The problem is I don't have mapping function, only I have the boundary. Also, based on my few conditions, I **don't need the position after deformation accurately.** At least the relative position of the points should be correct. That is suppose point b is between point a and point c, then after deformation, the point b is still between point a and point c

I am now trying to write a python program to solve this problem. But I am puzzled with the first step whether there is some formula or mathematics expressions for this question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. As stated, your question doesn't have a well-defined answer. If $A$ is the disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin in the plane $z = 0$ and if $B$ is the axis-oriented square centered at the origin and with side length $2$, what do you mean by _corresponding point_? (Further, a closed, unknotted curve in space does not uniquely define a surface, so there are other difficulties with your prospective question.) Could you please clarify what you're asking, what requirements a "solution" to your question should have?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you, I will update my answer. By the way, why a closed, unknotted curve in space does not uniquely define a surface? I can't find counterexample of that.

Comment: For example, a circle bounds a disk, or two distinct hemispheres, or a half-infinite cylinder, etc., etc. Do you have some specific property in mind if a curve is "bounding" a surface?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see, then the normal should be same.

Comment: So, your domains are flat, right? Then probably first you should rotate the plane of domain A towards the plane of domain B and then you actually need a mapping between two domains in the same plane.  And could you specify the class of acceptable transformations more precisely?

Comment: Sure @VorKir, as you said, the domains are flat. And I need first rotate and then in order to meet the boundary, I may  enlarging, shrinking or translation the domain